# Mongoose: Simple custom validation function not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose, schema

### Background

I am defining a Mongoose schema for countries, where I store the country name, and its [ISO alpha2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) and [ISO alpha3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3) codes.

These ISO codes, are just abbreviations for the country names. For example, Spain is ES, United Sates is US, and so on.

### Objective

My objective is to do schema validation so that the codes have the right amount of letters when inserting a country in the collection.

An ISO alpha2 code can only have 2 characters, and an ISO alpha3 code can have 3.

### Problem

To achieve this I have a validation function that checks if the given code has the correct size:

```
const hasValidFormat = (val, size) => val.length === size;
```

And I am trying to use this function as my validator:

```
"use strict";

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const hasValidFormat = (val, size) => val.length === size; 

const countrySchema = {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    isoCodes:{
        alpha2: { 
            type: String, 
            required:true,
            validate: {
                validator: hasValidFormat(val, 2),
                message: "Incorrect format for alpha-2 type ISO code."
            }
        },
        alpha3: { 
            type: String,
             validate: {
                validator: hasValidFormat(val, 3),
                message: "Incorrect format for alpha-3 type ISO code."
            }           
        }
    }
};


module.exports = new mongoose.Schema(countrySchema);
module.exports.countrySchema = countrySchema;
```

The problem is that I have the error `val is not defined` and the code wont run. This is confusing, because according to the [Mongoose docs for custom validators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html), the `validator` field is a function!

### However

If I change the previous code to:

```
"use strict";

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const hasValidFormat = (val, size) => val.length === size; 

const countrySchema = {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    isoCodes:{
        alpha2: { 
            type: String, 
            required:true,
            validate: {
                validator: val => hasValidFormat(val, 2),
                message: "Incorrect format for alpha-2 type ISO code."
            }
        },
        alpha3: { 
            type: String,
             validate: {
                validator: val => hasValidFormat(val, 3),
                message: "Incorrect format for alpha-3 type ISO code."
            }           
        }
    }
};


module.exports = new mongoose.Schema(countrySchema);
module.exports.countrySchema = countrySchema;
```

It will work!

### Question

Can someone explain me why the first example doesn't work, and the second does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `validator` function will take only one parameter.

According to the documentation, if the `validator` function takes two parameters, mongoose will assume the 2nd argument is a callback.

> "Custom validators can also be asynchronous. If your validator
>   function takes 2 arguments, mongoose will assume the 2nd argument is a
>   callback."

Source: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

You first code fails mainly because Mongoose is seeing it as an async validation, which is not the case. As a golden rule, validation functions should be inline.

You can achieve the behavior you are looking for bu using a closer function, like in the second code sample.

Thanks,

Comment: What you are saying would make sense, were this not JavaScript. If you pass extra parameters and if the function is not expecting them, it will ignore them. 

But if you are so sure, can you provide a documentation link to your explanation? Would love to read about it.

Comment: "Custom validators can also be asynchronous. If your validator function takes 2 arguments, mongoose will assume the 2nd argument is a callback."                                                                                               Please find above line on given link.

Comment: I understand. You found  something I didn't. I will fix the English grammar issues you have in your answer, upvote it and accept it.

Comment: Done. I hope you enjoy ! :D